# What are "large hadrons"? Are there also "small hadrons"?

Tags: particle-physics, terminology, large-hadron-collider

The BBC News article [Cern plans even larger hadron collider for physics search](https://www.bbc.com/news/science-environment-46862486) says:

> The difficulty with Cern's proposals for a larger Large Hadron Collider is that no one knows what energies will be needed to **crash large hadrons together** to discover the enigmatic, super particles that hold the keys to the new realm of particles.
>
> Cern hopes that its step-by-step proposal, first using electron-positron **and then electron-large hadron collisions** will enable its physicists to look for the ripples created by the super particles and so enable them to determine the energies that will be needed to find the super particles.

Do hadrons fall nicely into the two categories *large* and *small*? Is the way that the term *large hadron* is used in the article how particle scientists generally discuss experiments?

I'm (creatively) imagining the following sentence "We're not going to be able to do the experiment with these small hadrons, we're going to have to use the large ones."

**updates:**

- As of 24-Jan-2018 it still hasn't been fixed. When/if it is in the near future, I'll make a note if it here to be fair to the BBC.
- As of 30-Jan-2018 the first occurrence has been corrected but the second has not...

Comment: It's like [XKCD Hyphen](https://m.xkcd.com/37/), in reverse.

Comment: They are the ones collided at the large hadron collider, of course.

Comment: This amusing ambiguity only exists in languages like English, in which nouns can be chained (hadron collider = collider of hadrons). In other languages (like French) there is no such ambiguity: _grand collisionneur d'hadrons_.

Comment: All hadrons seem pretty small to me!

Comment: Although all hadrons are "large" by definition, and the two answers correctly explain the journalist's mistake, particles do fall into two categories large and small. Large particles are called hadrons. In practice, the "hadrons" in the Large Hadron Collider are either protons or ions. Mass of a proton: 10⁻27 kg; mass of electron: 10⁻30 kg. Thus a proton weighs about 1000 electrons. An ion is a big bundle of protons and neutrons. For instance, [lead ions were collided with protons](https://home.cern/news/news/accelerators/time-lead-collisions-lhc). Mass of lead ion: 208 times mass of proton.

Comment: @Stef a μ⁻ (lepton) is only 22% lighter than a π⁰ (hadron) and both are long enough lived to be put into modest beams.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The article is either a joke or a gross misinterpretation of the name “Large Hadron Collider”. The name refers to the physical size of the device. It is a “large” hadron collider, not a “large hadron” collider. There is no categorization of hadrons into “large” and “small”.

Comment: double check here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadron#Etymology

Comment: This is simply the etymology of the word hadron. It comes from the Greek *adros*, meaning large. This is to emphasize the fact that hadrons are composite particles in contrast with the elementary nature of the leptons - named from the Greek *leptos* meaning small.

Comment: Okay thank you. I almost didn't post the question because of that sentence.

Comment: Actually, that Greek word means stout, full grown, adult.
The implication here is "bulky".

Answer (score 1):

You could almost say that mesons and baryons could be small and large.   But I agree with Riley.   There is no such term as a small hadron